# empty desktop, but terminal desktop directory not empty

Tags: command-line

I was just cleaning up my desktop of old files, and am now left with a completely empty desktop. When I open up the Files UI and look at my desktop, it is also empty there.

However, when I open terminal and change directory to Desktop, I still see all of the files that used to be on my desktop. Why are these files still being listed even though my desktop appears to be empty?

Thank you.

Comment: What are these files? Can you give us their names?

Comment: Do the files still fail to show up on the desktop if you log out and log back in?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I deleted the files from my desktop, but they still show up via /Desktop when I `ls` in the terminal. I logged out and logged back in, and they still show up in the terminal. Since I deleted the files from my desktop, I was wondering why these files still appear in the terminal.

Comment: @edwinksl they are simple .txt files that I had on my desktop

Comment: could you please `cd Desktop` and then `ls -l` and append the output to your question? Do those files end in `~`?

Comment: @ridgy i get something like this : `text.txt~` along with the normal `text.txt`

Comment: Also, please post what this command says: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons`  If it says "false" , the solution might be pretty simple

Comment: @Serg it says "True"

Comment: @dhaneku.b  OK, that means your desktop is working fine, it's supposed to be displaying icons. What about filenames themselves ? Do they have a leading dot ? Filenames with leading dot like `.bashrc` are the hidden files and don't show up unless you specifically set your file manager to show them

Comment: @Serg I have no files that have a leading dot. I just had simple text files that were on my desktop. When I deleted them, they are not visually there on my desktop, but are there when I open desktop via terminal